# Reversing a global variable within function -- Python

Tags: python

```py
closes = []

def check_indicator():
    global closes
    closes.reverse()
    print(closes)


connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host='localhost',
    database='postgres',
    user='postgres',
    password='pass'
)
connection.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute('select closeprice from candles order by datetime desc limit 54')
closes.extend(cur.fetchall())

check_indicator()
```

When running the code above I get an unreversed list of `closes` what causes that to occur?
I have already declared `global closes` inside the function. However, when I declare a variable that depends on `closes` inside the function like this one `reversed_closes = closes.reverse()` this returns with `None`

Comment: what does `fetchall()` return? I guess it returns a list and you are appending that whole list to `closes`. So in the end you reverse a list with only a single element which does nothing. Also `global closes` is only required if you change to a different object of the variable (which you are not doing. So the line with global is not required).

Comment: why reverse `closes` inside a function when your function does not take any parameters? you don't really need to use `global closes` because you are not declaring any variable named `closes` in that scope.

Comment: @TimWoocker changed it to `extend` sorry that was a silly mistake but the issue still going persistent

Comment: How do you know it is unreversed if you only print it once, instead of both before and after? One reason you need to make a [mcve] is to eliminate the possibility that the problem is caused by something other than just the part of the code you showed us. If your question is about reversing a list then there should be no need for your example code to depend on a database connection, and since it does, that means nobody here can help you because we don't have your database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make another list and manually flip it; Here is how:

```py
list_1 = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
list_2 = []

for i in list_1[::-1]:
    list_2.append(i)

print(list_2)
```

If you want it in a function, you can do smth like this:

```py
def rev_list(list_item): # rev_list and list_item are changable if you like
    new_list = []
    for i in list_item[::-1]:
        new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
```

Hope I could help